# Determine where this function is continuous - floor function

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, continuity, alternative-proof, piecewise-continuity

Determine where this function is continuous:
$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 \frac{1}{x-\lfloor x\rfloor}, & \text{for } x \notin \mathbb{Z}\\
    1, & \text{for } x \in \mathbb{Z}\\
\end{cases} $$

Thanks! What I have so far:

Continuity is where the $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to a}} f(x)$ = $f(a)$.

This is certainly true because if we see $a$ as equal to $n + \delta$, then 
$$\frac{1}{n + \delta-\lfloor{x + \delta}\rfloor}$$
$$= \frac{1}{n+\delta -n}$$
$$= \frac{1}{\delta}$$

$f(a)$ is also equal to $\frac {1}{\delta}$, so therefore the function is continuous when $\delta \neq 0$. $\delta$ equals $0$ when $a$ is an integer. Therefore, this is continuous in the interval $(x, x+1)$.

Is there something wrong with this line of thought? And if there isn't, is there a more rigorous or faster way of doing this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Regarding a (marginally) faster way, you could observe that $g(x) = x = \lfloor x \rfloor$ is continuous and nonzero for noninteger $x$, hence the reciprocal $f(x) = 1/g(x)$ must also be continuous for noninteger $x$. Then, your argument shows that $f(x)$ isn't even bounded as $x$ approaches an integer from the right, so it certainly can't be continuous at integer values of $x$.

Comment: Thanks! @Bungo That does make sense.

Comment: Does anyone know how to prove this using the epsilon-delta definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a \in \mathbb{Z}$, we have $a+\frac1{n+1} \to a$ but $$f\left( a+\frac1{n+1}\right)=\frac{1}{a+\frac1{n+1}-a}=n+1 \to \infty \ne 1 = f(a)$$

Hence it is not continuous at integer values.

Notice that $f(x)$ is just $\frac1x$ on $(0,1)$, hence it is continuous on $(0,1)$.

Also $f$ is a periodic function with period $1$.

Hence $f$ is continous at $x$ if only if $x$ is not an integer.